# MSSQL Group by Percentage

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Im trying to find a way to group my results into 3 groups that are predefined 0-33%, 34-66% and 67-100%. The calculation is already being set as "Depletion". I want to group the top, middle and bottom of this column into the three different groups. Here is the query I'm using from multiple tables.

I assume I need to find the highest value in the SELECT first so that I can calculate the percentage, but I cant seem to find a way to do that. From there I dont know how to group the items based on percent.

```
SELECT     l.name AS Location, i.name AS ItemName, li.par, COUNT(*) AS Sales, li.par - COUNT(*) AS Depletion
FROM         shoppingcartdetail AS o INNER JOIN
                  item AS i ON i.id = o.itemid INNER JOIN
                  location AS l ON o.locationid = l.id INNER JOIN
                  location_item AS li ON i.id = li.itemid
WHERE     (CONVERT(datetime, o.created_date_time, 101) BETWEEN GETDATE() - l.service_interval AND GETDATE()) AND (o.locationid = 1)
GROUP BY i.barcode, i.name, l.name, li.par
```

Sample result

```
ItemName                 | avgshelflife | unitcost | par | Sales | Depletion
Dr. Pepper Bottle 20 oz  | 90           | 0.83     | 70  | 31    | 39
Mountain Dew Bottle 20 oz| NULL         |NULL      | 70  | 27    | 43
Coke Can 12 oz           | NULL         |NULL      | 30  | 22    | 8
M&M's Peanut 1.74 oz     | 90           | 0.60     | 66  | 14    | 52
Dr. Pepper Can 12 oz     | 180          | 0.38     | 30  | 13    | 17
```

Where M&M's Peanut 1.74 oz would by the 100% threshold with the highest Depletion of 52. Items would be grouped into the three groups with a new column added.

In this case: Y=%*52(Depletion of M&M's Peanut 1.74 oz)

```
Group0-30% is 0-17
Group31-66% is 18-34
Group66-100% is 35-52
```

Results

```
Group0-30% Coke Can 12 oz   
Group31-66% Dr. Pepper Can 12 oz
Group66-100% Dr. Pepper Bottle 20 oz, Mountain Dew Bottle 20 oz, M&M's Peanut 1.74 oz
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result in question

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question you want to display "Depletion" which is percentage that you need to display in group. If this so you can use like this.

```
select *,CASE 
    WHEN (Depletion < 34) THEN 
        'Group0-30%' + ItemName 
    ELSE 
        CASE 
            WHEN (Depletion < 67) THEN 
                'Group31-66%' + ItemName 
            ELSE 
                'Group66-100%' + ItemName 
        END
    END from (
        SELECT     l.name AS Location, i.name AS ItemName, li.par, COUNT(*) AS Sales, li.par - COUNT(*) AS Depletion
        FROM         shoppingcartdetail AS o INNER JOIN
                          item AS i ON i.id = o.itemid INNER JOIN
                          location AS l ON o.locationid = l.id INNER JOIN
                          location_item AS li ON i.id = li.itemid
        WHERE     (CONVERT(datetime, o.created_date_time, 101) BETWEEN GETDATE() - l.service_interval AND GETDATE()) AND (o.locationid = 1)
        GROUP BY i.barcode, i.name, l.name, li.par) t
```

If not like that then please provide with data for better understand.

Thanks,

Comment: Right now Im only calculating the level of depletion. Its not currently a percentage which is the other part I'm confused on executing. I edited my original post, but to clarify I need to find the highest Depletion and set that as the 100% threshold and then calculate.

Comment: I edited my post... Don't know this is helpful to you or not but I tried to make it perfect for you. please check and suggest it is useful or not

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need. The only thing I'm not doing that I cant figure out is how to find a MAX in the Depletion column and use it as my 100% marker. RIght now the Depletion is not a percent.

Comment: Cool.. :) enjoy your day :D

Answer (score 0):

this works(ugly though),the idea is to use top percent and then do the rest,i have used sales.orders table for demo purposes,but the idea remains the same..

step1: get all percentages into three temp tables,i have used three different temp tables due to identity col and laziness,you can do it with one

```
select top 33 percent * ,'37 pcnt' as 'pcnt'  into #temp1 from sales.orders order by orderdate desc

select top 67percent * ,'67 pcnt' as 'pcnt'  into #temp2 from sales.orders order by orderdate desc

select  * ,'100 pcnt' as 'pcnt'  into #temp3 from sales.orders
```

now next step is the place where we get data..

```
with cte
as
(
select * from #temp
union all
select * from
(
select * from #temp1 t1 where not exists(select 1 from #temp t2 where t2.orderid=t1.orderid) 
)c

)
select * from cte
union all
select * from
(
select * from #temp3 t3 where not exists(select 1 from cte where cte.orderid=t3.orderid)
)b
```

Output:
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare a function which calculates percent based on row number..below is the logic ,you may want to refine as per your needs..further point to note is some rows may say zero percent,but the rows returned are inline with top percent clause..

Orderid is  a PK in my demo,you can change it a unique number  or PK in your case

```
Alter function dbo.getpercent
(@orderid as int
)
returns int
as
begin

declare @pcnt int
;with cte
as
(
select row_number() over (order by orderid)  as rn,orderid
from sales.orders)
select @pcnt=(cast(rn as float)/830)*100 from cte 
where orderid=@orderid

return @pcnt
end

select dbo.getpercent(orderid) ,* from sales.orders
order by orderid
```